# How to remove style in all img tag using php?

Tags: php

I have `$_POST['detail'] =` this value

```
<p><img src="EVKQLW.jpg" style="width: 794px;"><u><b style="background-color: rgb(0, 255, 255);"><font color="#0000ff"><br></font></b></u><img src="jhjjQLW.jpg" style="background: red;"></p>
```

i want to remove style in all img tag using php, i'm looking for how to do in stackoverflow but not found please help me, how can i do ?

Comment: You have to use jquery to remove style from the tag

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP dom manipulation library:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php